# OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Is it possible to create an image in `OpenGL`, let's we created a ball and when touched it spins or something and then be able place it statically in a layout in xml.

so it would be be like:

```
TextView

openGL object we created

TextView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to place a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) between those two `TextView`.

There is a rotation sample in the sdk folder. Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

This blog explains about opengl and there is a lot of information made .Follow the 
[link](http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/).